# rss rome create entries with <content:encoded /> tag

Tags: java, rss, rome, rss2

Where can i find a simple tutorial on how to generate `<content:encoded />` tags in an rss using rome?

I've been reading throug their documentation but it is only about read and parse from a feed. And their javadoc is minimal...

Thank you!

Udo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javawsxml/Rome05TutorialFeedWriter) includes a part for creating an entry with data that has a content type of text/html:

```
entry = new SyndEntryImpl();
entry.setTitle("ROME v3.0");
entry.setLink("http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javawsxml/Rome03");
entry.setPublishedDate(DATE_PARSER.parse("2004-07-27"));
description = new SyndContentImpl();
description.setType("text/html");
description.setValue("<p>More Bug fixes, mor API changes, some new features and some Unit testing</p>"+
                     "<p>For details check the <a href=\"http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javawsxml/RomeChangesLog#RomeV03\">Changes Log</a></p>");
entry.setDescription(description);
entries.add(entry);
```

I think that should be transformed into a `content:encoded` element in the generated feed, perhaps depending on the feed type.

EDIT: this was my first answer, but it has nothing to do with ROME:

Don't know if this is what you're looking for, but the [RSS Best Practices Profile](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#namespace-elements-content-encoded) describes what should be in the element:

> The content:encoded element defines
>   the full content of an item
>   (optional). This element has a more
>   precise purpose than the description
>   element, which can be the full
>   content, a summary or some other form
>   of excerpt at the publisher's
>   discretion.
>
> The content must be suitable for
>   presentation as HTML and be encoded as
>   character data in the same manner as
>   the description element.